# xlwt: Is it possible to adjust the style of a cell after creating it?

Tags: python, xlwt

After you do:

```
sheet.write(0, 1, 'whatevs')
```

Is it still possible to adjust the style of cell 0,1. The reason I am asking is that I have a list of errors I loop and I would like to color all the cells red that have an error.

I could do it when I write the cell but it will make my code a little more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API exposed to do it, you could look at the source code and come up with a way:

```
rows = ws.get_rows()
rows[0]._Row_cells[0].xf_idx = styleindex
```

You can get the styleindex by adding a style you created.

```
style0 = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index red, bold on',
                 num_format_str='#,##0.00')
styleindex = wb.add_style(style0)
```

`wb` is a Workbook object and `ws` your Worksheet.

Beware: this isn't meant to be done this way, but I couldn't find another.